# Mediator, Fluent Validation & OneOf, как сделать pipeline?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7, mediatr

.net 7 web api, MediatoR 12, FluentValidation & OneOf, не могу сообразить как сделать PipelineBehavior, чтобы из него не надо было кидать исключение, если запрос не прошел проверку в пайплайне, а можно было вернуть `OneOf<bla_bla, ApiError>`, где в `ApiError` будут лежать ошибки валидации.
Wrappers:

```
public interface IMyRequest<TResponse> : IRequest<OneOf<ApiError, TResponse>>
{

}

public interface IMyRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestHandler<TRequest, OneOf<ApiError, TResponse>>
    where TRequest : IMyRequest<TResponse>
{

}
```

Pipeline:

```cs
internal sealed class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
    where TResponse : IOneOf, new()
```

Но таким образом никак нельзя вернуть `OneOf`, упорно пытается сказать, что не может преобразовать `OneOf` в `TResponse`:

```
return OneOf<ApiError, TResponse>.FromT0(new ApiError { Text = "Test" });
```

Как можно победить это всё?
Сделать 1 общий объект, в котором будет лежать и результат, и ошибки (если нет, то null, null не отдавать клиенту в json'e)? Но хотелось бы иметь функционал как у `OneOf`, чтобы метчить результаты на IActionResult (изобретать свой велосипед?).

Метод FromT0: [GitHub](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf/blob/7cd022ccc983c26abfb6ee3649986ec8b178336a/OneOf/OneOfT1.generated.cs#L72)

Comment: `(TResponse)OneOf...` не катит? Убрать `new()` если вы явно не вызываете конструктор `new TResponse()` или для чего оно? Сигнатура метода `FromT0` есть? Есть еще ковариантность и контрвариантность типа `<in TRequest, out TResponse>`.

Comment: `(TResponse)OneOf...` не катит тоже. `new()` осталось от других тестов, забыл убрать. FromT0 - принимает ApiError в себя и ничего больше.

Comment: Дубль два: сигнатуру метода `FromT0` покажите, отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Пожалуйста: https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf/blob/7cd022ccc983c26abfb6ee3649986ec8b178336a/OneOf/OneOfT1.generated.cs#L72

Comment: Вставьте в вопрос, это может быть важно для ответа - [edit]. `return (TResponse)(object)OneOf...` попробуйте. Или `(IOneOf)OneOf`

Comment: Тогда получается ошибка: ```System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'OneOf.OneOf`2[ApiError,OneOf.OneOf`2[ApiError,System.Boolean]]' to type 'OneOf.OneOf`2[ApiError,System.Boolean]'.```, если вернуть просто ```(TResponse)(object)new ApiError```, то будет ```System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ApiError' to type 'OneOf.OneOf`2[ApiError,System.Boolean]'.```

Comment: Есть, конечно, вариант, возвращать вообще только результат из обработчика, а в остальных случаях кидать Exception, но на другом форуме уже говорил, что это дорогая операция, хотелось бы без Exception'ов

Comment: Вот в тексте исключения явно обозначена проблема приведения. Вчитайтесь внимательно, вы запутались в типах.

Comment: Пока оставил эту затею, сделал на исключениях, посмотрим как вести себя будет, возможно так и оставим на исключениях всё это дело